# Android view draws cover status bar

Tags: android, layout, surfaceview

Device: HTC Sensation
OS: 4.0.3
Resolution: 
Problem: 
1 On the bottom we see gray part of the screen 
2 Progress bar cover part of status bar

[Here is the image](http://archmage.us/screenissue.jpg)

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ru.freecode.archmage.android.view.GameProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ru.freecode.archmage.android.view.surface.NetworkGameSurface
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```